# mvc3 Authorize attribute for active directory Security group which user is not direct memeber

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory

I have a 'ABC_grade_Users' group in active directory . I tried to get this group using >PrincipalSearchResult groups user.GetGroups() ,but this group does not show .
when I run GetAuthorizationGroups I get this group listed , that means there are 6 group which I am not a direct memeber.

I want to authorize user for this AD group using [Authorize(Roles = "Domain\ABC_grade_Users") ] attribut but since user is not a direct memeber of 'ABC-grade_users' , i get the false result that user is  not in roles .

My question is how can I authorize user with roles using authorize attribute . this work fine when I have group listed from GetGroups() method.

//not working -
        [Authorize(Roles = "Domain\ABC_grade_Users") ]
        public ActionResult EditRecord(int id, string elig, string IsTest)
        {                }

webconfig

Comment: what is your current authorization method? Membership API call? Cookie / Session? Please add the code from your logon method to your post.

Comment: this is window authenticantion, here is the entry of webconfig :   <authentication mode="Windows" /> <authorization> <deny users="?" /> </authorization> <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"> <providers> <clear /> <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" /> <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" /> </providers> </roleManager>

Comment: that helps, but even better would be to see your logon action method in your account controller

Comment: this is intranet app.user is redirect to application index page if autheticated using AD . no logon method required.

Comment: right, windows login. duh. Good question. Domain should handle this